# How to edit files in container docker by editor

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

I used `docker-compose` and ran my `container`. Mount data volume in `docker-compose.yml` as:

```
 version: '2'
 services:

 ### Workspace containter
 workspace: 
  build: ./workspace
  volumes_from:
    - volume_src

volume_src:
   build: ./volume/src
   volumes: 
     - ./src:/var/www/html
```

I ssh container `workspace` as permission `root`.

`docker-compose exec workspace bash`

`root@a4f923f71693:/var/www/html#`

I touch a file: `touch a.php`

Then I went to folder source code `src` on my host. I used my `sublime text` to edit. But permission not save.

```
datnq@quocdat-pc:~/web/src$ 
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 Th08  4 15:15 a.php
```

How can I edit files data volume by editor (not permision)

Comment: Did you try changing permissions on that file either via the root user inside the container or via sudo from the host?

Comment: @ldg: If i change my permission one file that is okie. But I want all files I create on the container always edit on my host.  Because I ssh by root, so all files i created on the container permissioned `root`. Then they mounts to my host with `root` permission. Certainly I can edit file if I dont use `root` permisson.

Comment: Check to see if there is a group named `docker` in your host and create it if not. Add the user you want to log in as to that group. More info about this is in the Docker docs in the installation section: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/create-a-docker-group

Comment: `datnq@quocdat-pc:~/web$ groups`

    `datnq docker`

My user login has belong to group `docker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how the touched file `a.php` is owned by root?

From your command line snippet, you are still logged in as user `datnq`.
So before you can do anything to the file you should be logged in as `root` first.

Assuming you are at `datnq@quocdat-pc:~/web/src$`

**Do:**
`sudo -s subl a.php`

Comment: Thanks @Samuel Toh: I see.  I tried your way. It works fine!


`Notice how the touched file a.php is owned by root? ` => I created file `a.php` in the container (SSH by root). So it sync to my host `src` is owned by root. 
`datnq@quocdat-pc:~/web/src$`

` -rw-r--r--  1 root                    root                    0 Th08  5 09:35 a.php`

Comment: Can I create files inside the container  and not sync by root permission?

Comment: Looking at the permissions you got on that file, it seems like other than the user `root` himself can do read, write and execute. World permission on it is suggesting `read and execute` only. Probably try doing chmod `757 a.php` inside the container and see if `subl a.php` on the host works. @QuocDat let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks, but if I chmod `757` means `others`  have full permission. I am affraid that they not secure.  Every time I create a file. I must chmod `757` for them. It is not good way :D . Anything else?

Comment: @QuocDat yep this is indeed not an elegant solution. To be honest, I'm not sure either so I did some research for you and this guy seems to have a "hacky" way around it by forcing the container to run its process as a user that the same `uid` as your logged in user. Obviously not the best solution but worth a try and then tweak things from there. see: https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/

Comment: Also, don't forget to mark this question as answered by clicking on the tick besides my answer if you think it is helpful to you in any ways, Thanks! Let me know how you go with the other guy's blog post.

Comment: thank you so much!  Sorry I dont have enough reputation to vote your answer.

Comment: @QuocDat you don't need reputation to mark your own question as answered :P Just click on the tick (check mark) beside (left hand side) my answer and that will do it. Thanks. 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow